# Postgres Elephant behind corporate http proxy

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm trying to access an online PostgreSql  database installed on Elephant SQL but I allways get connection refused. 
I found a github issue but it doesn't work either :https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/1035

```
            var pg = require('pg');

            var conString = "postgres://kdmvfgvn:ZNEhNxEsNPAb2IObsRu8mJpR3W_jlLM8@horton.elephantsql.com:5432/kdmvfgvn";

            var socks = require('socks5-client');

            var proxy_options= {
              host: 'user:pass@host',
              port: '2222'
            };

            var socksConn = socks.createConnection(proxy_options);


            const client = new pg.Client({
            user: "xxx",
            host: "horton.elephantsql.com",
            database: "xxx",
            password: "ZNEhNxEsNPAb2IObsRu8mJpR3W_jlLM8",
            port: "5432",
            stream: socksConn
             });
            console.log('1');

            client.connect((err) => {
              if (err) {
                console.error('connection error', err.stack)
              } else {
                console.log('connected')
              }
            })


            /*
            pool.query("SELECT NOW()", (err, res) => {
            console.log(err, res);
            pool.end();
            });*/
```

Comment: do you have a socks server running on `host:2222` ?

Comment: @mihai, I didn't want to show the real values

Comment: I agree, I was just asking if your socks server is running

Comment: I have a http proxy runnig

Comment: won't work...I'm assuming it's the http proxy your corporation gave you. That's not gonna work with random tcp traffic which socks provides.

Comment: @mihai do you know how to acess it with corporate http proxy?

Comment: no idea, I don't think it's possible, but I edited the title with this detail, perhaps you'll find an answer